# Python: how to unpack lists of different lengths into a string, using .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to unpack lists (of different lengths) directly into a string, using .format()?

This code works as expected:

```
list_of_ids = [1,2,3]

def generate_query(list_of_ids):
  list_of_ids_as_string = ', '.join(str(e) for e in list_of_ids)
  query = ('SELECT '
              'some.metrics '    
              'FROM ad_group '
              'WHERE campaign.id IN ({})'.format(list_of_ids_as_string)
              )
  return query 

query = generate_query(list_of_ids)
```

But if I try to unpack the list directly, only the first element will show up in the query:

```
def generate_query(list_of_ids):  
  query = ('SELECT '
              'some.metrics '    
              'FROM ad_group '
              'WHERE campaign.id IN ({})'.format(*list_of_ids)
              )
  return query
```

I know that I could do something like

```
              'WHERE campaign.id IN ({},{},{})'.format(*list_of_ids)
```

... but this does not help, if the passed lists are of different lengths.

So - is there a way to unpack lists (of different lengths) directly into a string, using .format()?

Comment: No and yes.  No if you are a reasonable person, yes if are ready to subclass `list`  and doctor its `__str__` method.

Answer (score -1):

You cam join the list given a defined separator.

```
“, ”.join(list_of_ids)
```

Which will yield a single string you can use inside your format call.